# sssd not working over ldap_id_use_start_tls

Tags: ssl, sssd

Have a weird situation going on. Trying to setup `sssd`, but I am having issues when I set `ldap_id_use_start_tls` on `sssd.conf`.

In `sssd.conf` I have the following config:

```
[domain]
ldap_id_use_start_tls = true
ldap_tls_cacert = /path/to/cert.pem
ldap_tls_reqcert = never
```

When I enable these options, I am not able to login to a new account on the server, I just get a message saying the password is invalid.

When I turn off the TLS options, everything works as expected, the new logins get their automatic home directory, etc..

I tried to validate my certificates with `ldapsearch`:

```
ldapsearch -D "DN of user" -W -h ldap.server.com -b "dc=ad,dc=site,dc=com" -s sub -ZZ "(objectclass=*)"
```

This query returns all of the ldiff information I was expecting. There is no issue with the LDAP server certificate according to OpenLDAP.

---

Any idea why `sssd` is failing on `ldap_id_use_start_tls`, but the `ldapsearch` looks like it's working fine?

Comment: This is Amazon Linux 2 btw

Comment: You need to enable sssd logs using "debug_level" to see more information. But in general sssd just uses libldap, so if ldapsearch works, sssd should work, too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to validate if its working with only the 2 first options:

```
ldap_id_use_start_tls = true

ldap_tls_cacert = /path/to/cert.pem
```

Also check that the `cert.pem` have the right permissions `0600 root:root`.

Answer (score 0):

Because your ldap.server.com server does not have required certificate for TLS connection. "ldap_id_use_start_tls = false" will work.
ldapsearch command request clear text connection in this situation.